# Will all futures passed to CompletableFuture.allOf() run?

Tags: java, semantics, completable-future

So I have a couple futures which I want to run, even if some fail I'd like all to have a chance to run. So if I do:

```
CompletableFuture.allOf(futures).join()
```

Will that be the case? My reasoning is that every future would have its own queed job in its executor and therefore all would run provided the main thread doesn't finish first. My issue is that I specifically `.join()` on `.allOf()` so my application doesnt end before running everything

So `allOf()` semantics confuse me: Will the future return complete when all of the passed futures complete regardless if successful? Or will it complete a failed future if it sees one failed without waiting for the rest?

**EDIT**

To illustrate my question further, does `.allOf` behaves like this:

```
Stream.of(futures).forEach(future -> {
  try {
    future.join()
  } catch (Throwable e) {
    //dont throw, we want to join the rest
  }
})
```

Or does it behaves like the following:

```
Stream.of(futures).forEach(future -> {
  try {
    future.join()
  } catch (Throwable e) {
    throw e; //All other remaining .join() wont run
  }
})
```

Which is it? first or second case? Since I want the first case thats what I'm using on my code temporarily, but I'd like to use `allOf()` if possible because its more aesthetic

Thanks!

Comment: From the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...-): "*Among the applications of this method is to await completion of a set of independent CompletableFutures before continuing a program, as in: CompletableFuture.allOf(c1, c2, c3).join();.*" - as for abrupt completion, thats also documented.

Comment: @VinceEmigh I think the question is different, if one of them fails, and you know at this point that the result is going to be a `CompletionException`, will all the others that potentially have not started *still* be executed? I mean suppose that they support interruptions, will an interrupt be send?

Comment: @VinceEmigh I dont see anything about "abrupt completion" so it'd be great if you could spell it it out.  @Eugene is right, also to add to his metaphore, will `allOf()` wait until all those future that havent still execute run and complete(failed or otherwise)?

Comment: It's worth noting that something like `join()` doesn't *make* the futures run. The asynchronous operations represented by the future objects are *already* running (or at least scheduled to run) -- otherwise you couldn't have a future in the first place. It's possible for operations in the future to fail, or to be cancelled, but that's independent of how you're waiting for them.

Comment: Fair point @DanielPryden, my intention is not making them run but to wait until all completed though, regardless if failed or successful, because otherwise my main thread would end leaving work undone. If `allOf()` would immediately fail and continue on say, a RuntimeException, it'd be bad. So question is: Does `allOf()` wait untill all completed or not?

Comment: Dear whoever cares, yes, it waits for every future to be completed regardless if it violently throws or otherwise. Mad props to commenters here, also, you cannot kill a thread in java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, each future will be independently attempted for completion.

I think you are also trying to understand how the control flows in various scenarios. I have come up with 4 scenarios :

1. A future where failure shall happens due to an unhandled exception
2. A future which shall be explicitly marked as failed with a completeExceptionally AND has an exceptionally block at its tail.
3. A future which shall be explicitly marked as failed with a completeExceptionally AND does not have an exceptionally block at its tail.
4. A future that shall complete to success.

```
//CASE 1
// A future that shall fail due to an unandled exception in its run 
// and has an exceptionally block at its tail
CompletableFuture<Void> unhandledFailureFutureWithExceptionHandler =
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        throw new RuntimeException("Exception in unhandledFailureFutureWithExceptionHandler");
    });
unhandledFailureFutureWithExceptionHandler = unhandledFailureFutureWithExceptionHandler
    .exceptionally(throwable -> {
        // Handling exception for this future
        // HANDLING POINT 1
        System.out.println("Handling exception at HANDLING POINT FOR CASE 1, 
            failure message is : " + throwable.getMessage());
        return null;
    });

//CASE 2
//A future that shall fail and has an exceptionally block at its tail
CompletableFuture<Void> failedFutureWithExceptionHandler = new CompletableFuture<>();
failedFutureWithExceptionHandler.completeExceptionally(
    new RuntimeException("Exception in failedFutureWithExceptionHandler")
);
failedFutureWithExceptionHandler = failedFutureWithExceptionHandler.exceptionally(throwable -> {
    // Handling exception for this future
    // HANDLING POINT 2
    System.out.println("Handling exception at HANDLING POINT FOR CASE 2, 
        failure message is : " + throwable.getMessage());
    return null;
});

//CASE 3
//A future that shall fail and has no exceptionally block at its tail
CompletableFuture<Void> failedFutureWithoutExceptionHandler = new CompletableFuture<>();
failedFutureWithoutExceptionHandler.completeExceptionally(
    new RuntimeException("Exception in failedFutureWithoutExceptionHandler")
);

//CASE 4
//A future that shall succeed and print a message to console
CompletableFuture<Void> successFuture = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> 
    System.out.println("CASE 4 : Running successFuture")
);

CompletableFuture.allOf(unhandledFailureFutureWithExceptionHandler, 
    failedFutureWithExceptionHandler, failedFutureWithoutExceptionHandler, successFuture)
        .exceptionally(throwable -> {
            // Handling exception if ANY of the futures that did not have its own exceptionally block
            // In this case the exception of `failedFutureWithoutExceptionHandler` will be handled here
            // HANDLING POINT 3
            System.out.println("Handling exception at HANDLING POINT FOR CASE 3, 
                failure message is : " + throwable.getMessage());
            return null;
        }).join();
```

The output produced on the console is

```
Handling exception at HANDLING POINT FOR CASE 1, failure message is : java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in unhandledFailureFutureWithExceptionHandler
Handling exception at HANDLING POINT FOR CASE 2, failure message is : Exception in failedFutureWithExceptionHandler
CASE 4 : Running successFuture
Handling exception at HANDLING POINT FOR CASE 3, failure message is : java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in failedFutureWithoutExceptionHandler
```

As you can see if a future throws an unhandled error as in case 1, if it has a `exceptionally` block chained to its tail, the exception shall be handled at that point

As for case 2, in case where the future is marked as failed with `completeExceptionally`, if the future has a handler chained to its tail, then the `exceptionally` block shall be handled by that block

In case 3, the future is marked as failed and does not have an exceptionally block, thus it shall be handled by the `exceptionally` block at the next level, in this case it is the `exceptionally` block of the `allOf()`.

As you can see, case 4 runs to completion and the message gets print on the console irrespective of the failures of the other futures.